# Problem setting FPU Control word

Tags: c++, c++builder, inline-assembly

I have a function that is part of a utilities library and it is failing unit tests created when compiled and run in C++ Builder. The problem function is below. When running the unit test the program seems to get stuck at the line `fldcw controlWord` and can't move past that. It seems to be waiting for something that will never occur. Any ideas?

```
void FPUControl::setControlWord(short controlWord)
{
    // set the control word - note this assembly construct works on 
    // Visual C++ and Borland C++, but may need to be changed for other
    // compilers
#ifndef __GNUC__
    __asm
    {
        fldcw controlWord
    }
#else
    asm volatile
    (
        "fldcw %[controlWord]"
    :
    : [controlWord] "m" (controlWord)
    );
#endif
}
```

Comment: You'd better reset the FPU before you do this so you don't get slapped with an exception right away.  FNINIT.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works fine for me (verified with C++ Builder 2007).

```
setControlWord(Default8087CW);
```

where `Default8087CW` is 4978.

Comment: Do you build in Release or Debug? - it works in release for me but not Debug. I'm using 2009.

Comment: I wouldn't consider C++ builder a valid C++ compiler.

Comment: @Zenikoder: So should I reply by verifying it against GCC or MSVC instead when the OP clearly stated C++ Builder??? Stop being a troll and grow up.

Comment: @Seth: Both release and debug are fine in 2007. I should note that we skipped version 2009 entirely after 1 hour of testing it after finding several critical compiler bugs.

Comment: @Matthieu: Why do you think so?

Answer (score 0):

@Zach: The code compiles and runs under C++Builder XE too. For the record, I did not include it as part of a class.